# How to change horizontal spacing in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

In my file, I have 32 subsections of a single section. In the table of contents, the titles of subsections numbered above ten are displayed directly next to to their number, without any space. Is there any way of adding extra space?

Comment: Which documentclass are you using?

Comment: I'm using article.

Comment: Do you use any packages, e.g., `tocloft`, to help manage the appearance of the ToC?

Comment: I'm not, currently.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `tocloft` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{4em} % more space for title numbers
% and the rest of the document
```

Change the `4em` to suit your document (it is normally `3.2em`).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you load the `tocloft` package, which is designed to help simplify modifying the appearance of the Table of Contents, List of Figures, and List of Tables.

Specifically, I would like to suggest that you add the following three instructions to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\cftsetindents{sec}{0em}{1.25em}
\cftsetindents{subsec}{1.25em}{2.75em}
```

The `\setcftindent` macro takes three arguments: (i) the sectioning header type (`part`, `sec`, `subsec`, `subsubsec`, etc.), (ii) the offset of the sectioning number from the left-hand edge of the text block, and (iii) the offset of the associated text.

The code shown above aligns the subsection-level numbers with the text of the associated section-level text, and it provides `2.75em-1.25em=1.5em` of space for the subsection-level numbers and the subsequent whitespace.

Feel free to modify one or both parameters to suit your (typesetting) tastes.